# JavaScript difference between two dates is wrong by one hour

Tags: javascript, date, time, difference

I'm trying to calculate the difference betweent two times, like 10:54 and 09:00 (expected difference is 1 hour 54 minutes):

```
Date.prototype.diffTime = function(date){
    return new Date(this-date);
}
```

But this returns one hour more than I expect:

```
Thu Jan 01 1970 10:54:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
Thu Jan 01 1970 09:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
Thu Jan 01 1970 02:54:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

So why does it add one hour? The input times are correct. When I use getTime(), I get 1.9 hours (this-date/1000/60/60), which is also correct.

Thank you for your comments. I now wrote a simpler function which does what I need:

```
function getTimeHHMI(date){
    var minutes = date/1000/60;
    var hours = Math.floor(minutes/60);
    minutes -= hours*60;

    return [hours, minutes].join(':'); // returns 1:54
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass `this-date` to `new Date`, the value is interpreted as a unix timestamp representing 1:54am. 1:54am in GMT+0 is the same as 2:54am in GMT+1. I.e. the browser converts the unix timestamp to your local time.

Converting the **duration** to a date value doesn't make sense, since duration is independent of time zones.

Answer (score 1):

this-date returns milliseconds .If you construct date from the difference , it would be date way long 1970

```
Date.prototype.diffTime = function(date){
    return (this-date)/1000/60/60;
}
```